# Ordered Downloadable Product title same

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order

[image]

I have Enclosed the issue on the screenshot, how can i fix this type issue, "Ordered Downloadable product titles are same." Title should showing the first downloadable product title on the ordered items.in Magento 1.9.1.0 please help me

I noticed the issue by getLinksTitle();
http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/downloadable-product-links-title-is-wrong-in-the-customer-order-view-and-in-the-admin-order-view-43820.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Spending more Hours, i was fixed the issue.

\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\downloadable\sales\items\column\downloadable\name.phtml

From

`<dt><?php echo $this->getLinksTitle(); ?></dt>`

to

```
<dt><?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getLinksTitle(); ?></dt>
```