# Multiple Downloadable Product Purchased through a single order Title Issue

Tags: magento-1.9

Purchasing the Multiple Downloadable Product in single Order. In admin order Shows First Product downloadable link to all other Products downloadable Title.  Getting ISsue. Please Help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Have a look on    [**ordered-downloadable-product-title-same**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136206/ordered-downloadable-product-title-same)

I already Fixed, Issue. Please Accept the same Once you Satisfied my answer

**For An Email:-**

app\design\frontend\theme\theme_dir\template\downloadable\email\order\items\order\downloadable.phtml

Use

```
<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getLinksTitle(); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $this->getLinksTitle(); ?>
```

Comment: For email ? Cannot Change. How can i change that too?

Comment: please have look on edited answer

Comment: Thanks Sir, Its Worked me.. thanks alot. spend a great time

Comment: @JohnS Please Once Search our magento.stackexchange.com Before You ask a new question, More Questions Solved, dont ask the same question as new one, thanks

Comment: okay sir, Thanks, This is my first post, thats why. sorry and thanks alot, helped me out of the issue !